# unrecognized jquery element in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, jquery

I have a popup displayed using ajax. This popup contains a form, this is how it looks like.

```
    <form id="edit_tailored_form" name="thisisthename" method="post" action="/edittailored">
        <h4>Country</h4>
        <p>Show only records from this country.</p>
        <ul>
            <li><label>Country:</label>
                <select class="inpt1" name="country">
                       <option value="0">ALL_COUNTRIES</option>
                       <option value="1">United States</option>
                       <option value="2">France</option>
                </select>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <h4>Hashtags</h4>
        <div class="clr" style="height:10px;"></div>
        <p>Show only records under these hashtags.</p>
        <ul>
            <li><label>Hashtags:</label><input type="text" name="hashtags_select" class="hashtags_select inpt1">

                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_btn" id="addhash_lst">+</a>
                <input type="hidden" class="cid" value="" />
                <div class="hashtags_list"></div></li>
            <li><label>&nbsp;</label>

                <div class="hashtags_display">
                    <ul>
                        <!-- display here the added hashtags--->
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="hashtags" class="hashtags_hdn" value="1,3,13">
        </ul>
        <div class="clr" style="height:0px;"></div>
        <h4>Save and quit</h4>
        Save the modification and quit.
        <ul>
            <li><label class="control_label">&nbsp;</label><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="close_popup">&nbsp;</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" id="edit_tailored_btn" class="btn1" value="Save" /></li>
        </ul>
    </form>
```

And in the javascript file, I added this action:

```
$('#edit_tailored_btn').live('click', function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        var data = $('#edit_tailored_form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/edittailored',
            data: data + '&ajx=2',
            type: 'post',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#add_record_wrapper').html(data);
            }
        });
    })
```

With edit_tailored_btn standing for the Id of the "save" button in the form.

as you can see, I serialize the form to get the data of its inputs so I can send them using ajax (again).

My problem is that the serialize like doesn't work in chrome (it works in firefox). A inspected that and found that it's not actually serialize which is not working, but my form is not recognized, as for `alert($('#edit_tailored_form').attr('name'));` displaying null.

Any idea?

Comment: Works in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/LKZD2/ -- post more information

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? .live() is deprecated since version 1.7, and was removed on 1.9.

Comment: I'm using 1.7 .. live works in too many other examples in my project

Comment: @ExplosionPills I edited my question, I've posted all the form html

Comment: Jquery .live() is deprecated since 1.7 use .on() or .bind()

Comment: @speti43 I will use on(), bind() or delegate() instead of live, but... note that this is not the problem, a hello world alert works fine inside live, in chrome and ff.

Comment: works fine http://jsfiddle.net/LKZD2/1/

Comment: @Lobo, I'm really confused about it, it works as you see... But it doesn't work in my project. (note that the form is a result of ajax query)

Comment: Is the form not recognized before the ajax submit or after ajax submit?

Comment: Before ajax submit @evilReiko , I have ajax result inside ajax result, the first returns the popup, the second saves edits of the popup

Comment: 1)Try adding ";" in the end of the "live" binding. 2)is the "live" binding in `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });`?

Comment: Yes, it's in a `$(document).ready(function(){..});` close...

Comment: I copied the jquery code, and put it in the html code file (using <script></script> tags) and it works. it works on both chrome and ff, 

If I put it in the js file, it works only on ff.

Comment: ok, in the "live" binding, add `alert($('#edit_tailored_form').length); alert($('#edit_tailored_btn').length);` on click, you should see 2 alerts each displays "1", to make sure you have only 1 form of id "edit_tailored_form" and 1 button of id "edit_tailored_btn"

Comment: Yeah, I have only elements with one id each. No repetitive id @evilReiko

Comment: Note that if I made it in the same html file in <script> tag, it works on chrome. Otherwise, no

Comment: You're probably replacing the form with another form, or maybe not attaching the popup form correctly. Ok, here's on good thing to trace. in the "live" binding, do `alert($('html').html());`. Copy the result of the alert in a new file, you will be able to see the entire altered-by-ajax html

Comment: You're right, when I add it, it doesn't show the `<form>` tag in the console.log, it displays only its containt from `<h4>Country</h4>` (in the example above. @evilReiko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem, When the popup loads, it loads actually in a `<div>` which is contained in an html form (the form which triggers the event displaying the popup)...

This results in two html forms, one inside the other, so Chrome ignores the child... I didn't pay attention to this problem.

As for Firefox, it doesn't ignore none of them. It gives priority to the form whose submit button is the clicked one.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Glad to know you could figure it out